# States: Positivity vs. Continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

**Definition**

Define positivity in terms of:
$$\omega\geq0:\iff\omega(X^*X)\geq0$$
*(This way it serves best for the GNS-construction.)*

**Problem**

Given a C*-algebra $1\notin\mathcal{A}$.

Consider a linear functional $\omega:\mathcal{A}\to\mathbb{C}$.

> Then one has the equivalence:
>   $$\omega\geq0\iff\|\omega\|=\lim\omega(E)$$

**Attempt**

Reduce the problem to positive elements:
$$\|Z\|\leq1:\quad|\omega(Z)|\leq|\omega(X_+)|+|\omega(X_-)|+|\omega(Y_+)|+|\omega(Y_-)|$$
Remember the estimate on norms:
$$Z=\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}i^\alpha Z_\alpha:\quad\|Z_\alpha\|\leq\|Z\|$$

Now, how to establish a bound:
$$A\geq0:\quad\omega(A)\leq\|\omega\|_+<\infty\quad(\|A\|\leq1)$$
*(I found it in Bratelli & Robinson. Unfortunately, I don't understand it.)*

Proceed with the overall enclosing inequality:
$$|\omega(A)|^2\leftarrow|\omega(AE)|^2\leq\omega(A^*A)\omega(E^2)\leq\|\omega\|_+^2\leq\|\omega\|^2$$
*(Beware for limessuperior as the square is not operator-monotonic!)*

Especially one has: $\lim\omega(E)=\sup\omega(E)=\|\omega\|_+=\|\omega\|$

**Attention**

Meanwhile, I got it. Answers are still heartly welcome!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**

My excuses; meanwhile I understood the proof.

**Proof**

Assume for contradiction that:
$$A_n\geq0:\quad\omega(A_n)\geq n\quad(\|A_n\|\leq1)$$

Consider the absolutely convergent series:
$$S_N:=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^2}A_n\to S\in\mathcal{A}$$
*(Remember that the positive cone is closed!)*

By positivity one has an upper bound:
$$S_N\leq S\implies\omega(S_N)\leq S$$

Then one derives a contradiction:
$$\infty\leftarrow\sum_n\frac{1}{n}\leq\omega(S_N)\leq\omega(S)$$

*(Remember that increasing positive elements increases norm!)*